# How can i divide TX and RX packet BPF filter?

Tags: java, wireshark, bpf

I'm using BPF packet filter as below source code)

```
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP|BPF_K|BPF_JEQ, 0x86dd, 0, 0x6),  // ipv6
    BPF_STMT(BPF_LD|BPF_B|BPF_ABS, 0x6),              // goto protocol
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP|BPF_K|BPF_JEQ, 0x11, 0, 0xf),    // udp?
    BPF_STMT(BPF_LD|BPF_H|BPF_ABS, 0x28),             // goto source port
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP|BPF_K|BPF_JEQ, 0x35, 0xc, 0),    // sport == 53?
    BPF_STMT(BPF_LD|BPF_H|BPF_ABS, 0x2a),             // goto dest port
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP|BPF_K|BPF_JEQ, 0x35, 0xa, 0xb),  // dport == 53?
```

But i want to divide tx or rx packet like to 'Linux cooked capture' in wireshark

[image]

So how can i use BPF_STMT for get linux cooked capture field(LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL)?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by "divide tx or rx packet"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. [SLL](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SLL) is not an actual network protocol, so you will never see it used when attaching eBPF programs to the kernel.

[Libpcap](https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL.html) and Wireshark encapsulate packets when using cooked capture mode(capturing from multiple interfaces at once). These tools do this to add information you can normally infer from the interface, but since you can have packets from multiple interfaces mixed, we need SLL to add this information on a per-packet basis.

The options available are:

- 0, if the packet was specifically sent to us by somebody else;
- 1, if the packet was broadcast by somebody else;
- 2, if the packet was multicast, but not broadcast, by somebody else;
- 3, if the packet was sent to somebody else by somebody else;
- 4, if the packet was sent by us.

To know if you are the sender or the receiver you need to know what your own IP/MAC address is. Since we don't have that info we can use these hints to see if something is incoming traffic(0), outgoing(4), routed via us(3), ect. But when you attach your eBPF program, you can infer this info in other ways.